# How do we access Solana's Devnet explorer?

Tags: devnet, explorers

Is there a Blockchain explorer for Solana Devnet? Or can everything be searched on Solscan?

Answer (score 1):

You can set all the explorers to devnet as well.

on https://explorer.solana.com/ you can find that setting in the top right corner:

[image]